# resizing image based on rules in php

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I know how to resize an image keeping its ratio based on these formulas :

Width Formula :

Orig H / Orig W * New W = New H

Height Forula :

Orig W / Orig H * New H = New W

But i have set a maximum width before the image is resized and a maximum height value too.
So how do i work it with two maximum values ??

Say the max height was 600 and the max height was 100 ??

The answer is probably staring me in the face..

This is what i have just now using just the height.

```
            $image_size = new Image(DIR_IMAGE.'data/signatures/'.$file);
            $w_size = $image_size->info['width'];
            $h_size = $image_size->info['height'];
            $w_new_size = round($w_size/$h_size*100);
            $h_new_size = 100;
```

I guess what i'm trying to say is i don't want the image to go above the set width or set height but it has to keep its ratio.

Some show me the light ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let php.net show you the light:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Example #2 is doing what you ask for, isn't it?